# Magento 2 - Sendgrid extension

Tags: module, magento2.2

I tried to install a new extension on my Magento site (version 2.2.0).
I created a new folder in **app/code/** like this

> app/code/SendGrid/EmailDeliverySimplified

After that I run this command

```
php -f bin/magento module:enable --clear-static-content SendGrid_EmailDeliverySimplified
```

I had this return **"The following modules have been enabled : -SendGrid_EmailDeliverySimplified"**.
To be sure, I upgrade and recompile my site.

When I go in the admin panel, I see my module in the "System" menu :

[image]

When I click on "Settings" or "Statistics", I have this error message :

[image]

Could you help me please?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you clear cache using `php bin/magento ca:fl`?

Comment: Yes, I did it @PYYick but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **[SMTP for Magento 2](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/)**. SendGrid SMTP works with this.